# Jquery UI (draggable) blocking active Pseudo class in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, firefox

I had encountered an issue while working with the following css.

```
#keyboard li:active {
        color:red;
}
```

html block:

```
<ul id="keyboard">
           <li id="a"  class="letter">a</li>
           <li id="aA" class="letter">aA</li>
           <li id="ai" class="letter">ai</li>
 </ul>
```

I was trying to figure out why it was not working in my web page but works else where with just some plain HTML and CSS.

Then I tried removing my jqueryui.js file then that css block works.
How to resolve this issue without removing the jqueryui from web page.

I am loading my css after loading jqueryui.

Update:

I had figured out that draggable method is making this issue. The entire list is in a div which is made draggable using jquery. I made a fiddle of my problem.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t96ku5na/

Comment mentioned by @TJ https://jsfiddle.net/t96ku5na/3/ says it works fine and closed but its not working.

**Update:**

This issue seems to be firefox specific. It works perfectly in Chrome.
Firefox tested version:45.0.2.

Comment: Try adding `color:red !important;` But this is not a good way to follow specificity...

Comment: tried but stiil issue exists

Comment: Add !important to your code `li:active {color:red !important;}`

Comment: use proper selectors for your li - like `#yourid li:active{your code !important;}`

Comment: Can you show us rendered `html`.. ??

Comment: my original css has proper selectors this one is just for reference @user6028084

Comment: try adding your stylesheet below jqueryui.js.. Might help

Comment: @user6028084 updated question with fiddle

Comment: @TJ http://greensock.com/forums/topic/12769-draggable-only-firefox-refuses-to-click/?p=55436

Answer (score 0):

I was just running into this same issue in firefox, but the [jQuery draggable API](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#theming) actually provides a work-around now with Themes. You can use the class `.ui-draggable-dragging` to refer to the element while it's being dragged (i.e. when it's being clicked on, the same as pseudo class `:active`).